# Magento 2:- Add new column into sales_shipment_grid and set that column data from sales_shipment table

Tags: magento2

I want to add delivery date into shipment grid, already save data into sales_shipment table.
added column using sales_order_shipment_grid.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_shipment_columns">
        <column name="delivery_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delivery Date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
</columns>
    </listing>
```

di.xml file is for get data is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="ShipmentGridAggregator" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="string">sales_shipment.delivery_date</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

but it is not working. the column is created but not showing that data.
Look forward your reply